# Fedora 14 command line: assign folder permissions

Tags: linux, fedora, chmod

How can I assign folder permissions in Fedora 14 using the command line?

I'd like to give read/write/execute permissions to :

- 2 users (tom, jim) to the folder /Home/Share
- 1 group (employees) to the folder /Home/Share/Employees

However, I'm not sure how to do this properly from a shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is using `chown`. Take a look at these :

http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/chown/

http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html

http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/02/how-to-change-ownership-of-files-and-directories-in-unix/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the whole [user/group/others stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions) in Unix, that might help. But it looks like you want to set up stuff that is *very* awkward for more than a few groups. Perhaps what you need is finer granularity, as the ACL (Access Control Lists) offer on some filesystems. Check out the manual pages for acl(5), setfacl(1) and nearby ones.